# CORS Policy issue only on Azure VM IIS when Login 'auth/Token', but other API is working. And in local everything works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors, cross-domain

"has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

Everything works fine when I test it on local. But when I deployed it to Azure VM using IIS, /auth/Token api will prompt the error in the title. But the other api's are all good. No CORS policy issues. I've tried everything. Like:

Setting up webconfig:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

and other settings to allow all cors. Everything works fine on local. No cors policy encounter.
My only issue is when Login, and triggering the /auth/Token which is deployed on Azure VM using IIS. But when Login using local all works fine.
Anyone can suggest or help me please. It's been 3days on this issue.

Comment: anyone can help me? :'(